# mod_rewrite (Apache 2.4) RewriteBase outside htdocs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I stuck on a problem trying to get a my rewrite rules working.

Assume the following setup:

### Folder structure like this:

```
app/
web/                         <--- Document-Root
    .htaccess                <--- My mod_rewrite rules
    index.php   

vendor/
    company/
        package/
            Folder/
                Route.php
```

---

The vhost points to "web/" as Document-Root and the security is reduced 
so all overrides are allowed:

```
<Directory "~PATH~\web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now i try to rewrite simply every request (*) to "Route.php" (internal! no 301 or something).
For my understanding if if would call "www.example.com/a/b" then i would expect that the
request is internal redirected to ~PATH~/vendor/vendor/company/package/Folder/Route.php
where i can fetch everything and take the request in PHP for further processing.

But the rewrite fails. Maybe its not possible to traverse a directory up "/../" ?!

### Content of .htacces:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /../vendor/company/package/Folder
    RewriteRule .* - [E=ROUTER:Route.php]

    # route calls to router /x/y/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . %{env:ROUTER}?mode=htaccess [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

---

Any help appreciated :) 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you have `autoload.php` file in your vendor directory which you can require inside your `web/index.php` file and it work without navigating to any directory. Just remember setup the basic Front Controller pattern in your `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule .* ../vendor/company/package/Folder/Router.php [L]   
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried it on my local machine.

This Setup works:

```
RewriteRule .* vendor/company/package/Folder/Router.php [L]
```

Seems like its not allowed to forward the Request to directories higher than the Docroot.
I've found this post:

[htaccess RewriteRule redirecting to parent directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787008/htaccess-rewriterule-redirecting-to-parent-directory)

The important Part:

**You can't rewrite to outside the document-root. This is a security thing.**

**EDIT2:**

More Information: [mod_rewrite - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](http://webauth.stanford.edu/manual/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

***Quote:***

> **URL-path**
>   A DocumentRoot-relative path to the resource to be served. Note that mod_rewrite tries to guess whether you have specified a file-system path or a URL-path by checking to see if the first segment of the path exists at the root of the file-system. For example, if you specify a Substitution string of /www/file.html, then this will be treated as a URL-path unless a directory named www exists at the root or your file-system (or, in the case of using rewrites in a .htaccess file, relative to your document root), in which case it will be treated as a file-system path. If you wish other URL-mapping directives (such as Alias) to be applied to the resulting URL-path, use the [PT] flag as described below.

Comment: Thanks so far alphalynx ... The result is an error 404

This is the error log for mod_rewrite with trace level 8:

http://pastebin.com/3aq9cpQ4

Comment: I can confirm the same for me. Having vendor/ on the same level like .htaccess everything works fine. Now its also a bit more clear why Symfony uses this way: https://github.com/eventhorizonpl/symfony-community/blob/master/web/.htaccess - Maybe i use a similar approach :) Thank you for your help!