# Too many redirects error and browser shows

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, document-root

[With Reference htaccess RewriteRule redirecting to parent directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787008/htaccess-rewriterule-redirecting-to-parent-directory/39637281#39637281)

Thank you Francesco Casula, your answer was very helpful, application now redirects from one document root to other. I am facing infinite redirects issue.

I have following repositories with different version.

1. /var/www/portal/version/1.1.1/public/ binded with (api.somedomain.com)
2. /var/www/portal/version/1.1.2/public/
3. /var/www/portal/version/1.1.3/public/
4. /var/www/portal/version/1.1.4/public/

I want to execute api in following order (by version)

api.somedomain.com/qr    ---> /var/www/portal/version/1.1.1/public/

api.somedomain.com/v2/qr ---> /var/www/portal/version/1.1.2/public/

api.somedomain.com/v3/qr ---> /var/www/portal/version/1.1.3/public/

api.somedomain.com/v4/qr ---> /var/www/portal/version/1.1.4/public/

My httpd.conf is

```
 AliasMatch ^/v2/(.*)$ "/var/www/portal/version/1.1.2/public/"
 <Directory "/var/www/portal/version/1.1.2/public">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
.
.
AliasMatch ^/v4/(.*)$ "/var/www/portal/version/1.1.4/public/"
 <Directory "/var/www/portal/version/1.1.4/public">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

and .htaccess in /var/www/portal/version/1.1.4/public/ contains

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/v2/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v2/index.php [QSA,L] # p2 is the symlink name!

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

When I hit **https://api.somedomain.com/v2/invitebysms**

I get too many redirects error and browser shows

https://api.somedomain.com/v2/invitebysms/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/

Comment: Given that you appear to have access to the main server configuration file, you'll *greatly* decrease the complexity of your ruleset if you just put your configuration there, rather than bringing .htaccess files into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're going for is the following:

```
Alias /v4/ /var/www/portal/version/1.1.4/public/
<Directory /var/www/portal/version/1.1.4/public/>
  Require all granted
  FallbackResource /v4/index.php
</Directory>
```

In as far as I understand what you're trying to accomplish, the above, in your server config (delete the .htaccess file entirely) will do what you want. (Repeat for v2, v3, and so on.)

I am assuming here that you're running at least 2.2.16 or later, and preferably 2.4. If not, let me know, and we'll try again.

Comment: Thank you Bowen, My apache version is 2.4.7. I did the same changes as you suggested but now getting 404.