# htacess redirecting to js & css files

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess

This is my typical PHP MVC Structure:

```
-Resources
        --/my.css
        --/my.js
-Project
        --/.htaccess
        --/index.php
        --/Other Files & Folders
```

This is my htaccess configuration:

```
Options -Indexes

#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Write now my all requests are going through index.php. In my project files, I am accessing my css & js files located in Resources folder like following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../Resources/my.css"/>
<script src="/../Resources/my.js"></script>
```

This result in following error

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 258ms
```

I tried to add following Rewrite rule in htaccess configuration, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Resources/my.css
RewriteRule ^api(.*)$ ../Resources/my.css [NC,QSA,L]
```

I don't want to change my folder structure, since the same CSS & JS resources are shared between multiple projects, and it's easy to manage them from single location. I just want to reference them somehow.

I also don't want to include the code in my project file, like : `include('../Resources/my.css')` in PHP, I don't want this.

Please provide a solution to this.
Thanks and Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess RewriteRule redirecting to parent directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787008/htaccess-rewriterule-redirecting-to-parent-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as other also have pointed out in comments and answers, this is **NOT POSSIBLE**. We can't refer above or outside of our Project Root from client side scripting. We can do things from server side coding, but client-side code, not possible/

Answer (score 0):

By us it's kind of an unwritten role to always put assets in sub-directories of root dir (the dir containing the `index.php` file is root).

Anyway, you can't rewrite to outside the document-root. This is a security thing, and just think about it, does `example.com/../my-dir` make any sense?

---

A *workaround* (like in [another-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787008/htaccess-rewriterule-redirecting-to-parent-directory)) would be to create a symbol-link to your `Resources` dir, lets name it `mySymbolLink` then you could do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^Resources/.*
    RewriteRule ^Resources/(.*)$ /mySymbolLink/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But you still need to change the paths, for example, `/../Resources/my.js` should be `/Resources/my.js` to work.

Comment: No. Although it changes the error now. HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 231ms

Comment: What happens if you type in browser `your-site.com/Resources/my.css` directly?
Is it a real server or emulated on windows? Note that, of course `your-site.com/../Resources/my.css` is a bad request.
Also, above should be added to your existing rules (not replace them all).

Comment: The problem is the two dots, ../Rescouces. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} res/scripts/my.js
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../Resources/scripts/my.js [QSA,L]. This works perfectly on localhost, but on live server, it doesn't. May be it's true, whatever you do, we can't redirect outside of DOCUMENT_ROOT. But I don't know why it is working perfectly on localhost, after all, it's accessing outside DOCUMENT_ROOT at localhost

Comment: That is why I told you to create a symbol-link, as you noticed, the easiest way is to move your dir to be a sub-directory, cause, even with my work-around you still need to change all paths. anyway if this helped you consider accepting it ;-)